# sql server - error converting float to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a float field, I need to convert it as varchar and I need to add a leading zero when it contains only one nummber(it can contains 1 or 2 numbers). This is my query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(((LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(floatField,2))))), '00')
```

but I get an error:data type for argument 1 is not valid. I know I can do this in a different way, but I want to understand what's wrong in this

Comment: `FORMAT` function expects `numeric` or `datetime` data types as [first argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: Your first argument to `FORMAT` is already a string. Strings can't be formatted. Also, `STR` is a hideous function richly steeped in legacy for which there's no use if you have `FORMAT`.

Comment: SELECT FORMAT(1.23456, '00.000000')

Comment: Note, you have a float _column_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format` takes a `float` (among other things) and converts it to a varchar. Don't try to do its job for it:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(myfloat, '00') 
FROM   mytable
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9743f09c15ef988305d3eb1990d341f9)